# validation on checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I am building a project on attendance management. In one of the forms of my project, I have multiple checkboxes. I want that at least one checkbox must be checked for form submission. I tried with Javascript but the problem is, it flag an alert even if one or more checkbox is checked.

Here is my js code :

```
function validat(){
            var a = document.getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
            var bool=false;
            for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                if(a[i].checked==true){
                    bool=true;
                }
            }
            if(bool){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                alert("Sorry!Please select checkbox corresponding to students involved in duty leaves.");
                return false;
            }
```

Here's my checkbox code :

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name=duty[]' value='$row[university_roll_no]'></td></tr>";
```

Comment: log the value of `bol` before `if(bool){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need at least one checkbox to be checked you don't have to loop through all the checkboxes in your form. In the first found checkkbox you can stop.

```
function validat(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
    var atLeastOneCheckBoxIsChecked = false;
    for( var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++ ){
        if( checkboxes[i].checked == true ){
            atLeastOneCheckBoxIsChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(atLeastOneCheckBoxIsChecked){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry!Please select checkbox corresponding to students involved in duty leaves.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

A more *functional* way to do the same thing, is to be use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
function validat(){
    var atLeastOneCheckBoxIsChecked = document.getElementsByTagName("checkbox")
                                              .some(checkbox => checkbox.checked == true);

    if(atLeastOneCheckBoxIsChecked){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry!Please select checkbox corresponding to students involved in duty leaves.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example:

```js
function check() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var checkedOne = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkboxes).some(x => x.checked);

  if (!checkedOne) {
    console.log('please check at least one box!');
  }
  console.log(checkedOne);

}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Choose some monster features</legend>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="scales" name="feature" onClick=check()
               value="scales" checked />
        <label for="scales">Scales</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="horns" name="feature" onClick=check()
               value="horns" />
        <label for="horns">Horns</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="claws" name="feature" onClick=check()
               value="claws" />
        <label for="claws">Claws</label>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `input` elements and check if `type` is `"checkbox"`:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
            bool=true;
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
```

to

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have preferred you to use `jQuery` but with what you currently have, you need to do this:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

And then:

```
if(a[i].type == 'checkbox' && a[i].checked==true){
  // Checked alert
}
```